# Why does `ack` not produce output when used with `bash` like this?

Tags: bash, ack

I'm guessing this has nothing to do with `ack` but more with `bash`:

Here we create `file.txt` containing the string `foobar` so`ack` can find `foobar` in it:

```
> echo foobar > file.txt
> echo 'ack foobar file.txt' > ack.sh
> bash ack.sh
foobar
> bash < ack.sh
foobar
```

So far so good. But why doesn't ack find anything in it like this?

```
> cat ack.sh | bash
(no output)
```

or

```
> echo 'ack foobar file.txt' | bash
(no output)
```

Why doesn't `ack` find `foobar` in the last two cases?

Adding `unbuffer` (from expect) in front makes it work, which I don't understand:

```
> echo 'unbuffer ack foobar file.txt' | bash
foobar
```

Even stranger:

```
> cat ack2.sh
echo running
ack foobar file.txt
echo running again
unbuffer ack foobar file.txt

# Behaves as I'd expect
> bash ack2.sh
running
foobar
running again
foobar

# Strange output
> cat ack2.sh | bash
running
unbuffer ack foobar file.txt
```

What's up with *this* output? It echos `unbuffer ack foobar file.txt` but not `running again`? Huh?

Comment: it's an `ack` issue. Try to replace `ack` by `grep` and it works as expected.

Comment: looks like ack isn't happy that stdin isn't a terminal when running `cat ack.sh | bash`. I'd file file a bug for `ack`. Or just use `grep` ;)

Comment: Note that explicitly redirecting standard input of ack also solves the problem: `echo 'ack foobar file.txt <&-' | bash` or `echo 'ack foobar file.txt </dev/null' | bash`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ack` gets confused because stdin is a pipe rather than a terminal. You need to pass the `--nofilter` option to force `ack` to treat stdin as a tty.

This:

```
# ack.sh
ack --nofilter foobar file.txt
```

works:

```
$ cat ack.sh | bash
foobar
```

---

If you ask me, that behaviour is quite unexpected. Probably it is expected when someone understand the concepts of `ack` which I do not atm. I would expect that `ack` doesn't look at stdin when filename arguments are passed to it.

---

Why does `unbuffer` "solve" the problem?

`unbuffer`, following it's [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html), does not attempt to read from stdin:

> ```
>   Normally, unbuffer does not read from stdin.  This  simplifies  use  of
>    unbuffer in some situations.  To use unbuffer in a pipeline, use the -p
>    flag. ...
> ```

Looks like `ack` tries to be **too!** smart about stdin here. If it is empty it does not read from `stdin` and looks at the filenames passed to it. Again, imo it would be correct to not look at stdin at all if filename arguments are present.

Comment: `I would expect that ack doesn't look at stdin when filename arguments are passed to it.`  That's exactly right.

Comment: You agree that it is a bug?

Comment: No, it's intentional.  If ack doesn't get a filename or directory, it goes and finds files for you in the tree starting in the current directory.  It will only look on stdin if there's something on stdin for it to use.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case we pass the filename `file.txt`. Imo `ack` must not look at stdin in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The big mismatch here is that ack was never intended to be used in shell scripts. It's meant as a command line tool for humans.  That means that it makes some assumptions and optimizations for humans.  For example, by default ack's output is different if it's going to a terminal vs. getting redirected in a pipe.  There's also dangers in using ack in a shell script because its behavior can be affected by ackrc files and environment variables.  If you're going to be using ack in a script, you should be using the `--noenv` flag.  Better still, for shell scripts I'd use plain ol' grep.

What is the use case that brought up this problem?

Comment: Good to have the author here on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Hi @AndyLester, Putting `--noenv` in my script doesn't change anything. I'm using ack and not grep because I want to `--ignore-dir` and `--ignore-file`. I'm piping the output of `git diff origin/master | perl -ne <find removed function names> | ack` to make sure I've handled all case where they were used.

Comment: grep has `--ignore-dir` and `--ignore-file`, but they're called `--exclude-dir` and `--exclude`.  And if you're piping into `ack` then the `--ignore-dir` and `--ignore-file` have no effect anyway.  Maybe post your entire script the ack-users mailing list on Google Groups and we can help you through it there.

Comment: And `--noenv` won't affect anything here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is a bug – ack could look at stdin, however in a **NON BLOCKING** way. It is a bug to hang over a pipe that's empty…